# antd upload api: how to return promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise, antd

I am working with antd framework and I have to use upload API.
This is the signature:

***action: Uploading URL :  string|(file) => Promise***

I am invoking the API in this way trying to return a Promise:

```
    <Upload {...propsUpload}>
       <Button> <Icon type="upload" />Upload</Button>
    </Upload>
```

with propsUpload that refers to function uploadMedia

```
    const propsUpload = {
        action: this.uploadMedia,
        listType: 'picture',
        defaultFileList: [],
        className: 'upload-list-inline',
     };
```

and this is the function uploadMedia

```
    uploadMedia = (file) => {

       let formData = new FormData();
       formData.append('file', file);
       formData.append('uuid', this.generateuuid());
       formData.append('domain', 'POST');
       formData.append('filename', file.name );

       return fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + 
          '/v100/media/upload', {
       method: 'POST',
       credentials: 'include',
       headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json'
       },
       body: formData
       })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => data.data)
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error fetching profile ' + error)
      })      
    }
```

**The file is uploaded to server correctly.**
But after the call to API, antd try to do another call that fails, maybe because I am not returning the correct value from function.

As result the thumbnail is displayed with red border and and error is shownd. In the image below there are both (the call that fails and image with red border)

[image]

What type of object I have to return in function uploadMedia to use api correctly?

Thanks

Comment: what is `process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL` ?

Comment: It's a variable containg the URL of server. Please note that the call to server works fine and image is uploaded on server.

Comment: I just saw the url in the console which for some reason contains `[object20object]`. I Guess it should not be there

Comment: @AlexandrZavalii thanks for response. The problem seems that fetch return a json object instead of a promise and it's treated as url.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are not clear how to actually implement it (and it is unclear in docs):

Just implement a customRequest function in the props that accepts two callbacks, which are onError and onSuccess, and other data such as file and filename.

Like this

```
const props = {
    customRequest: (componentsData) => {

      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', componentsData.file);
      formData.append('uuid', this.generateuuid());
      formData.append('domain', 'POST');
      formData.append('filename', componentsData.file.name );

      fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + '/v100/media/upload', {
         method: 'POST',
         credentials: 'include',
         headers: {
           Accept: 'application/json'
         },
         body: formData
      })
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(data => data.data)
     .then(data=> componentsData.onSuccess())
     .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error fetching profile ' + error)
        componentsData.onError("Error uploading image")
      })      
    }
}
```

And let Upload component receive the props.

```
const App = () => {
    return <Upload {...props} />
}
```

Comment: Nope, I just provided a clearer and functional approach for guys like you can copy and paste in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used antd but looking at the docs of [`Uplaod`](https://ant.design/components/upload/) component I think you're using it wrong. Look at the examples there and see the code, `action` expects either a URL or a Promise that will return this URl. And `Upload` in this case will make request itself, so you don't need to do `fetch`. And your promise returns the `data` (object) so the Upload sends the request to `[object Object]` (which is what's returned by `.toString()` when applied to an object in JS)

#### EDIT

Try to check all examples in docs, I can see that there is an example when you want to manually upload the file (if you really need it)

Comment: Thank you @GProst, you are right I was using the API in the wrong way. Correct way is to use customRequest.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking to access the response object after calling the API. There are two ways you can get access to the response.

1. Implement a custom API request mentioned as in other answers for this question.
2. Use the onChange method provided by AntD (Which is the easier than utilizing the custom request)

I will explain the second approach below using a code block.

```
const fileUploadProps = {
    name: "file",
    action: config.remote + "api/file",
    method: "POST",
    showUploadList: false,
    headers: {
        authorization: "authorization-text",
        contentType: "multipart/form-data"
    },
    onChange(info) {
        if (info.file.status === "done") {
            const { response } = info.file;
            updateProfile(response.payload.file);
        } else if (info.file.status === "error") {
            message.error("Error uploading the file");
            props.endLoad();
        }
    },
    beforeUpload(file) {
        const isJpgOrPng = file.type === "image/jpeg" || file.type === "image/png";
        if (!isJpgOrPng) {
            message.error("You can only upload JPG/PNG file!");
        }
        const isLt2M = file.size / 1024 / 1024 < 2;
        const isGT20K = file.size / 1024 > 20;
        if (!isLt2M) {
            message.error("Image must smaller than 2MB!");
        }
        if (!isGT20K) {
            message.error("Image must larger than 20KB!");
        }

        if (isJpgOrPng && isLt2M && isGT20K) {
            props.startLoad();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

In Render function I have the AntD upload component

```
<Upload {...fileUploadProps}>
     <Button icon={<CameraFilled style={{ fontSize: "30px" }} />}></Button>
</Upload>
```

You can notice how I got the access to the response object inside **onChange** function.
Once the upload is complete it will call the **onChange** function having **response** object inside the **info** object.

So from there you can get access to your data object easily and call the next method.

Answer (score 0):

I solved using api customRequest in this way:

```
    uploadMedia = (componentsData) => {

      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', componentsData.file);
      formData.append('uuid', this.generateuuid());
      formData.append('domain', 'POST');
      formData.append('filename', componentsData.file.name );

      fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + '/v100/media/upload', {
         method: 'POST',
         credentials: 'include',
         headers: {
           Accept: 'application/json'
         },
         body: formData
      })
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(data => data.data)
     .then(data=> componentsData.onSuccess())
     .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error fetching profile ' + error)
        componentsData.onError("Error uploading image")
      })      
    }
```